# How to separate and safe textblocks and open them afterwards? C++

Tags: c++, file, text, save

I want to safe a Textblock (including new lines and every type of Char) seperated from the next one. All this has to be saved in one file and I would like to open them afterwards (for further processing). How can I save them seperated?

A example:
A simple solution would be if I write a comma after every textblock. But I can't open them correctly, if there is a comma too in the textblock.

I'm searching for a sign to put in between those textblocks, that I can seperate those textblocks. But, it have to be a sign that isn't valid as a char.

Thanks everyone for helping - have a great weekend :)

Comment: What is a "Textblock" if not comma-separated? Where does the data come from? – *But, it have to be a sign that isn't valid as a char.* – How are these "Textblocks" stored if not in `std::string`s?

Comment: It is a std::string... and it's just a user input, like a personal diary. I know, I could use '\0' but I don't really like that. Maybe there will be some numbers between those textblocks (also stored for later use) and something like a comma would be better. Hmm... maybe I can deactivate the search of commas whilst searching in a string.    Are there any other options?

Comment: So the user decides when a "Textblock" ends?

Comment: exactly. This textblock could be anything.

Comment: So it must be something the user can input. Then it can't be: *it have to be a sign that isn't valid as a char.*

Comment: How about EOF? (ctrl+d on unix, ctrl+z on windows)?

Comment: Oh, I understood you wrong. The user is writing a text and after that he use a button to safe the text. Now I will have a string with the user input. After some more I would like to save them mixed with some integers seperated in a file.

Comment: Then give the user a button to click when he's finished with his entry, then save it? what does "mixed with some integers" mean?

Comment: yes, but better change back to english, other languages are not allowed here on SO.

Comment: *Das Problem ist, das ich nicht genau weiss wie ich diese Einträge voneinander trennen soll.* – I thought you wanted one file per entry? Just use the current date and time as filename?

Comment: Oh, I feel sorry for you. I see you really want to help me and I appreciate that. I would prefer one file for a better order.

Comment: i misunderstood it. all entries in one file? seperate them by '`\0`'.

Comment: Yes, one file, all entries in there. They can be numbers and strings to be stored in order. I'll do it with '\0', I can't see a better option. Thanks

Comment: seperate them by `'\0'`!? It's something the user is very unlikely to enter ...

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I know it wasn't that easy. Next time, I will definitely think more in advance.

Comment: No problem, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

This example is for basic illustration. You can go for standards like json, xml or others. They will also have fitting escape functions, which will mostly work the same way.

In your example this escape character would have to be a comma.

**Escaping**

As you save a block of text, you replace all commas "," with the string "\c".

You can then use "," to separate text blocks, because all commas in the text block are now "\c". 
Be aware, that you also need to escape your escape character first. ("\" -> "\")

**Splitting**

When you try to find a separation between the texts, you search for a comma.

**Unescaping**

When you read back your text block, and have found the proper begin and end, replace the "\" by "\" and "\c" by "," again.

Comment: Thanks @stena - that is my problem

Comment: You are welcome @ratloser. If you can use my answer, please upvote and/or accept it. :)

Comment: I did :) 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @ratloser thank you. Could you maybe also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?

Answer (score -1):

You can to use a json like this:

```
 {
    "Text_1": "string",
    "Text_2": "string",
    "Text_3": "string",
}
```

Also i recommend you this library

https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think this is a littlebit awkward. I would need to write "Text_1": "string" every time into the file -> bigger files. And the main problem appears when the user input contains one token that I use to seperate the strings... like in your example a comma, colon or something like that. But anyway, I will have a look at this library, thank you :)

Comment: you are welcome! this is a great form to write or access to the textblock what you need, for example for write:

json j;

// add a string that is stored as std::string
j["name"] = "hjshdjkadhasjkdhaskjdad";

and  for read:

std::ifstream i("file.json");
json j;
i >> j;

auto text_ = j["text_1"].get<std::string>();